# How can I capture fastapi websocket messages without html/js?

Tags: python, web, websocket, fastapi

Fastapi docs include a [websocket example](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/) that receives data via html/javascript.  Saving the script as `main.py` and running `uvicorn main:app --reload`, the example works as expected:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WebSocket Chat</h1>
        <form action="" onsubmit="sendMessage(event)">
            <input type="text" id="messageText" autocomplete="off"/>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <ul id='messages'>
        </ul>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws");
            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                var messages = document.getElementById('messages')
                var message = document.createElement('li')
                var content = document.createTextNode(event.data)
                message.appendChild(content)
                messages.appendChild(message)
            };
            function sendMessage(event) {
                var input = document.getElementById("messageText")
                ws.send(input.value)
                input.value = ''
                event.preventDefault()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
"""


@app.get("/")
async def get():
    return HTMLResponse(html)


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        await websocket.send_text(f"Message text was: {data}")
```

How can I modify this example to write websocket messages to file without using any html/js?  I'd like direct access to the incoming data (text/json) with python and I'm unable to capture it directly.  Any additional info/clarity is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you mind elaborating further on that in you question? Also, do you need to write on a file the messages received on the server or on the client? It's not clear to me

Comment: I want to write messages received by the client to file.

Comment: Javascript runs on the browser and has no direct access to local files. If can keep an interface (UI), get the messages and then hack it to simulate the download of a file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872790/fill-in-a-file-upload-input-with-file-from-javascript if that can suit your case

Comment: What about using a python script that connects and logs messages like https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html ?

Comment: yes that works - but this question is about using fastapi's websocket support

Comment: I'm not getting the question then. Fastapi provides an endpoint to connect with a websocket from anywhere. In this example it also provides an html part to show how a browser may establish the connection. If your server is up an running, you can connect with a websocket

Comment: please reread the question.  I can use fastapi to connect to a websocket from the example above.  I'd like to do so *without the need for html/javascript*.  It's probably a simple fix, but I was not able to write websocket to file without HTML/js

Answer (score 2):

So, probably in the comments I didn't explain myself well.

From what I understood you want to connect via python to your webserver with a websocket and log to file the messages the server sends to your python script on the client. In simpler terms, you need to mimic the html/js part via python.

#### TL;DR

The server is already there, you just need to connect to it.

Here's the code snippet that you have to copy and paste in a different file and run when the webserver is already running. Note that the webserver doesn't need to be changed, if not for the two line within the `while True` loop. These can go away and you may change them with something like `await websocket.send_text("text")`

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8000/ws"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send("Hello world!")
        res = await websocket.recv()
        print(res)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

I'm not sure what messages you need to write to file, but the code snippet above is working and is the basis for what you need.